# PhpStorm Less watcher not working with clean-css plugin and autoprefix

Tags: less, phpstorm

I have a following problem with Less. I have configured Less file watcher to work with PhpStorm and so far everything is working. Now I have added a few plugins clean-css and autoprefix and suddenly everything stops working.

The error I get:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/less-plugin-autoprefix/lib/clean-css-processor' in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less-plugin-clean-css/lib/index.js on line 1, column 29:
```

My parameters are:

```
$FileName$ ../../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css --no-color $FileNameWithoutExtension$ --clean-css --autoprefix="last 5 versions"
```

clean-css plugin and autoprefixs are only working alone. If I add them together I get the error. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you run actual command in terminal? How did you install those plugins (what commands did you use)? Double check your parameters -- it looks broken to me (e.g. what second `$FileNameWithoutExtension$` does there? why all `--parameter` are after file names -- they better be in front etc)

Comment: npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css and npm install -g less-plugin-autoprefix i am using ubuntu

Comment: i changed up my parameter: `--no-color --clean-css --autoprefix="last 5 versions" $FileName$ ../../css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` but i still get the same error. @LazyOne

Comment: If i remove any of them then they will start working. But if i add both of them they start conflicting.

Comment: What is the actual command that gets executed (it must show it when error occurs)? **BTW:** I do see the same error

Comment: Whatever I try I do get the same even in terminal. So it must be Less or one of those plugins issue. This might be related -- keep digging there: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3187